# How to make my site stop adjusting after a certain point

Tags: html, css

I want my site to stop resizing (stop being responsive and lock at the desired size) after user minimizes it to a certain point lets say 10inch screen in pixels and when u scroll left of right it is not responsive after that point.

I have tried

```
body {
    min-height:30%;
    min-width:30%;
}
```

But nothing happens at all.

Comment: percentage of what? i call user `min-height:30vh` instead of `min-height:30%` same goes for `min-width:30vw` for `min-width:30%`. But if you want to use `%` you then have to set the width and height of the parent element `:root{width: 100vw; height: 100vh}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[percentage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage)**

> The percentage CSS data type represents a percentage value. It
>   is often used to define a size as relative to an element's parent
>   object. Numerous properties can use percentages, such as width,
>   height, margin, padding, and font-size.

use `min-height:30vh` instead of `min-height:30%` same goes for `min-width:30vw` for `min-width:30%`. But if you want to use `%` you then have to set the `width` and `height` of the parent element

```
:root{width: 100vw; height: 100vh}
```

or

```
html{width: 100vw; height: 100vh}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for media query my friend. check this out:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

you'll use a media query to specify the pixel size (and other options) for example 600px max width is a good measurement for phones. inside the query, you'll write regular CSS to apply under those size conditions.

let me know if you need samples, i'll send you some of my code to help.

here is another good post on stack

[Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't seem the 1st link at least this is not for mobile I have algorithm for dedirection in mobile

Comment: i edited my question so it becomes more clear sry for any inconvenience